# Unable to load saved value in MultiselectList chosen

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi Im new on using ListBox MultiSelectList , My problem is I cant fetch the value onload of my page, Here is my Code

In My Controller to Initialize the dropdown values

```
var getddlName = (from a in nameList
                                      where a.personId != null
                                      && a.personId != 0
                                      select new SelectListItem
                                      {
                                          Value = a.personId.ToString(),
                                          Text = a.personFullname
                                      }).ToList();
            ViewBag.ddlNameList = getddlName;
```

To Get the Saved value and Load it onload

```
if (ddlPersonIds != null)
            {
                List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
                var empIds = ddlPersonIds.Split(',');
                foreach(var c in empIds){

                list1.Add(c);
                }

               ViewBag.ddlPersonName = list1;

            }
```

And in my View here is how I pass the value to the MultiselectList

I created variable container in HTML head

```
var ddlNameList = ViewBag.ddlNameList;
var ddlPersonName = ViewBag.ddlPersonName;
```

and my MultiselectList

```
<div class="editor-field">


 @Html.ListBox("PersonIds", new MultiSelectList(ddlNameList, "Value", "Text", ddlPersonName), new { data_placeholder = "Select Employees...", @class = "chosen input-long-75", multiple = "multiple" })
                            </div>
```

EDIT: Even though I get the value in `ddlPersonName` it is unable to show and get selected in `ddlNameList`

Thanks

Comment: You're using the id of people as the value, not their names. But you're passing a string, which i assume is a name, as the selected value. I think that might be why? Try setting Value to personFullname as well and see if it selects it.

Comment: What is the `ddlPersonIds`? I tried to reproduce your issue in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NgGpop) but still don't know what `ddlPersionIds` is. Is that listbox still empty and/or cannot post selected values from it?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto sir the Value of `ddlPersonIds` are strings concat by `,` delimiter like ` "101,191,202"`

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto i just cant get the selected onload, not selecting the `ddlPersonIds` values

Comment: I found that the list is shown properly with certain option lists in modified version of the fiddle. Are you want to say that the list box is still empty after the page is loaded?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto it shows the list but not selecting the names that is already been saved

Comment: I tried in the fiddle and I could retrieve the selected values when `PersonIds` property set as `List<int>`, `int[]` `List<string>` or `string[]` type with current setup as provided in question. Therefore, I think the problem is `PersonIds` property used other type than mentioned before.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to resolve this?